# matlab ODE45 solves Differential equations with two variables of same order

Tags: matlab, math, ode

I have a Differential equations such as below in matlab format

```
syms x y m g r l J
% x,y are variables, the others are constant

1:  0.5*m*(r^2*x^2+l^2*(Dx-Dy)^2+2*r*l*Dx*(Dx-Dy)*cos(y))+0.5*J*(Dx-Dy)^2=m*g*
(l*sin(x-y)-r*(1-cos(x)));
2:  J*(D2x-D2y)+l^2*(D2x-D2y)-r*l*(Dx)^2*sin(y)+r*l*D2x*cos(y)-m*g*l*cos(x-y)=0,
3:  x(0)=pi/2,y(0)=pi/2,Dx(0)=0,Dy(0)=0,
```

I want to use ODE45 method to solve it, but I don't know how to use it in such a situation

Answer (score 0):

You need to solve for D2x and D2y to get an explicit ODE. Since there is only one equation for them, what you have is a DAE, differential-algebraic equation (system).

Thus you either employ a DAE solver or you have to compute the derivative of the first equation to get a second equation for the second derivatives, isolate them (if necessary, using a numerical solver) and then solve it as a second order ODE.

```
eq3 = diff(eq1, t)

deriv(t,w)
   x,y,Dx,Dy = w

   solve(eq2,eq3 for D2x,D2y)

   deriv = [ Dx, Dy, D2x, D2y ]
```